# Change array according to the sequence

Tags: c#, arrays

I have some Image sliders, and I wanted to change the sequence of the image slider. Current sequence is set from a database field (fetch the set of sequence numbers from the database and show it).

Now, I want to change the sequence number.Lets say,
My slider sequence is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` & I need to change the 4th position slider to 8th position and after that my slider number sequence is `1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9, 10`.

Here is an image to make it easy to understand
[image: CLICK HERE]

I have a int array with current sequence,

```
int[] currentSequence = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

MyCode:

```
int[] currentSequence = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var currentPosition = iproductrepositroy.GetSingle(x => x.ProductName.Equals(ProductName)).ProductSequence;// 4th position
var expectedPosition = ChangeSequence;// 8th position

if (currentPosition < expectedPosition)//right shift -->
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = (int)currentPosition + 1; i < expectedPosition; i++)
    {
        // I wanted to know how to change the above array here
    }
}
else//left shift <--
{
    int i;
    for (i = (int)currentPosition - 1; i > expectedPosition; i--)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be easier for you to do in a List:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int currentPosition = 3;
        int expectedPosition = 7;

        int adjust = (currentPosition < expectedPosition) ? 1 : 0;
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        var item = list[currentPosition];
        list.RemoveAt(currentPosition);
        list.Insert(expectedPosition - adjust , item); //Insert position may be one less at the moment, so use calculated adjustment

        foreach (int i in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
        var discard = Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, it's very easy to go back and forth from arrays to lists, to.  You can construct a list from an array (or call `ToList()`): `List<int> list = new List<int>(currentSequence);`  And you  can convert a List back to an Array: `list.ToArray()`;

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood your requirements then this is the simplest way to do the reordering:

```
var currentSequence = new [] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
var reordering = new [] { 1,2,3,5,6,7,4,8,9,10 };

var reorderedSequence =
    reordering
        .Select(r => currentSequence[r - 1])
        .ToArray();
```

To show that this works, try it with this:

```
var currentSequence = new [] { "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J" };
```

That gives back:

```
{ "A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "G", "D", "H", "I", "J" }
```